# How to return person with max sales in salesperson program- JAVA [PT. 2]

Tags: java

Sorry if I'm being bothersome. But I am stuck on another part of my HW problem. I am now tasked at instead of having an salesperson 0, salespersons start with 1. I have tried to solve this by parsing the strings i to an integer and adding 1. Seemed like it would work. However, for some reason the calculating of min is not correct. It stays at 0. I've tried stepping through the code and seeing why, but I cannot see it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Cray {
public static void main(String[] args){

    final int SALESPEOPLE = 5;
    int[] sales = new int[SALESPEOPLE];
    int sum, randomValue, numGreater = 0;
    int max = sales[0];
    int min = sales[0];
    int maxperson = 0;
    int minperson = 0;



    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i=0; i<sales.length; i++)
        {
        //To attempt print out the information of salesperson 0 and salesperson 1, I returned the integer value of i and added one.
        System.out.print("Enter sales for salesperson " + Integer.valueOf(i+1) + ": ");
        sales[i] = scan.nextInt();

        //max if statemnent works fine and is correct
        if(sales[i] > max){
            max= sales[i];
            maxperson = i;
        }
        //For some reason max is calculating but not min. 
        if(sales[i] < min){
            min = sales [i];
            minperson= i;
        }


        }



    System.out.println("\nSalesperson   Sales");
    System.out.println("--------------------");
    sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<sales.length; i++)
        {
        System.out.println("     " + Integer.valueOf(i+1) + "         " + sales[i]);
        sum += sales[i];
        }

    System.out.println("\nTotal sales: " + sum);
    System.out.println("Average sales: " + sum/5);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Salesperson " + Integer.valueOf(maxperson+1) + " had the most sales with " + max );
    System.out.println("Salesperson " + Integer.valueOf(minperson+1) + " had the least sales with " + min);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Enter any value to compare to the sales team: ");
    randomValue = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    for(int r=0; r < sales.length; r++){
        if(sales[r] > randomValue){
            numGreater++;
            System.out.println("Salesperson " + Integer.valueOf(r+1) + " exceeded that amount with " + sales[r]);
        }

    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("In total, " + numGreater + " people exceeded that value");

      }

    }
```

Comment: Interesting. Hmmm. I entered a -1 for one of the sales values of the array and it calculated that as the min correctly. Any positive integers return as min = 0.

Comment: you don't init minimum, so it starts with 0 (the default sales[0] value). you need to put a large value as t\he minimum first value,

Comment: That makes sense. However, I tried initializing to sales[5] (the max of the array) and it gave me an index error.

Comment: Nevermind I just initialized it to 5 and it works fine. I understand now because I am trying to find the minimum value I should start at a large number. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `min` is never set as all positive sales will be > 0

You should initialise `min` as a large value so that a positive sales figure *can* be less then the minimum value specified in your `if` statement:

```
if (sales[i] < min) {
```

You could use:

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Comment: That does work. But using that max value method is outside the scope of the work we're doing. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: This is the standard way of doing this but you could also set the `min` value in the first iteration.